# Bot, microsoft framework and Self-signed certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, chatbot

I'm not being able to connect with the Microsoft Framework for Bot and my webservice because the necessity of a certificate. I've tried it with a self-signed but it is not accepted by Microsoft.

Do you know some way to workaround this? It is necessary to link with the Microsoft Framework in order to open the communication channels and a CA certificate has a lot of costs. Using Azure is not an option.

Juan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop your bot on Microsoft Bot framework then you should definitely own an azure subscription to publish your bot. else you will get the certificate issues and more over self signed certificates will not be applicable in this case. I can understand what exactly your problem is bcoz I have faced this earlier.